# Custom Apple Push Notification Server vs Urban Airship and likings

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to implement the push notifications for one of my projects. Some of the possibilities I evaluated are:

- building my own APN sending script on the server
- using Urban Airship

Which one would you guys recommend and why?

NB. I know Urban Airship costs a bit, but assume that the 1 mil free notifications are enough for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you've kinda answered your own question really haven't you?

the positives of doing it yourself are that you get unlimited for free and probably have more control (although a push notification is a push notification is a push notification... how much control do you really need).

the positives of urban airship are that you save time/effort/resources. You don't have to maintain anything or fix any bugs.

I'm assuming if you send over a million push notifications you can probably monetise your app and thus pay for the service anyway. Remember a million is a huge amount. You can send 100 people 10,000 push notifications.

Comment: So aside the gazillion free push notifications and a few hours saved of deploying, no other benefits, right? I still think I'm missing something, otherwise I can't see who'd pay them :)

Comment: same reason why people don't host websites themselves. its too much work, too much effort, it requires extra knowledge that they might not already have and any attempt that they make will probably be less effective and more flawed than a professional solution. Plus if you're sending out millions of push notifications (eg: facebook) you might not have the resources to do this yourself.

Comment: UA cofounder here. We offer a lot of features to make the integration on your end as simple as possible. Things like tags and aliases make it really easy to get up and running, and if you're doing simple things like sending out broadcasts from an RSS feed, we take care of that automatically. Also, if you expand to other platforms, we also offer BlackBerry and Android support. Feel free to email us if you have any questions - support@urbanairship.com.

Comment: @Michael, Thanks for the tips. I'll be keeping you guys on my radar.

Answer (score 5):

You should also consider [Xtify](http://www.xtify.com).

Similar to Urban Airship, Xtify will save you time/effort/resources but should you choose to expand to other platforms beyond iPhone such as Android and Blackberry etc. which don't have native push support you can use one API's handle all of your notifications.

Xtify also includes tools to allow you to easily leverage things like location, with your notifications or independently.  For example you could configure notifications to automatically be generated based on a users location.

As for price, Xtify gives you [unlimited notifications](http://www.xtify.com/plans-and-pricing) for upto 250k users...

When we did our evaluation, the location data and management tools proved to be a huge differentiator for us.

Answer (score 1):

Manic Networks is selling servers, that send notifications to iOS, Android, BB and Microsoft.  Best bang for the buck if you ask me.

Comment: Any idea why their website is down? www.manicnetworks.com

Answer (score 0):

Urban Airship api is simpler compared to your own custom implementation for APNS. 
You also have advantage of having a single api for all iOS, Android and Blackberry. 
If clubbed together with their mobile app api, I think they also provide reports. 
and in case your app becomes very successful later and you want to do your own custom implementation then you can always go back to your implementation.