# Cross Platform Mobile Push Notifications

Tags: mobile, push-notification, cross-platform

I know this isn't directly programming related, but couldn't find another StackExchange site to post this on. I'm using a minimally customizable template to create a few dozen mobile apps (under one publisher) using PhoneGap, and need to push notification messages to all users across the following platforms:

- Android
- iOS
- Windows Phone
- Blackberry OS 7+

We have a custom backend powered by ASP.NET MVC that needs to send notifications to mobile app users based on various events that are raised - such as when a certain date is reached send a certain message, or for announcements, as well as to send notifications about special offers.

I'm unsure if a full-blown push notification service like PushWhoosh or PubNub subscriptions are worth investing in or if we should rather opt for each platform's own service such as Apple's APNS and Android's GCM (not too sure what Blackberry services are available for push messaging to BB OS 7+).

I would really appreciate if someone could shed a little light on this matter and will tremendously help my decision making process.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you try out those at QuickBlox (it's free of charge).

Here's the guide for iOS: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios

And the Android one: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-android

Not sure about Windows Phone and Blackberry though.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, that has just been my problem...I can't seem to find *one* that works across all 4.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure one exists. :(

Comment: As I figured...I'm just wondering, instead of investing in a subscription to facilitate all platforms, whether I should not just implement in code the call to the respective devices' push service? So when an event happens, I'll manually call APNS, GCM, Microsoft Push Sevrice, and Blackberry Push Service. Would this be an effective alternative?

Comment: Actually, I've just checked up on QuickBlox, and they do seem to support all 4 platforms: http://quickblox.com/modules/messages/
And PubNub as well: http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/mobile/

Comment: Hi Jeff. Sorry for not posting back sooner. We actually decided to go with each platform's native push service. The subscription costs for the volumes we are anticipating are out of our budget.

Answer (score 4):

After finding a similar thread here on SO ([Custom Apple Push Notification Server vs Urban Airship and likings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881799/custom-apple-push-notification-server-vs-urban-airship-and-likings)), I've decided that it would be best to instead leverage each platform's native push service:

- Apple Push Notification Service (APNS): [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)
- Google Cloud Messaging (GCM): [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)
- Microsoft Push Notification Service (MPNS): [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff941099(v=vs.105).aspx)
- BlackBerry Push Access Protocol (PAP): [here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/51382/) and [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/services/push/)

Alternatively, use the open source [PushSharp Library](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp).

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

[IBM MobileFirst](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2014/12/31/unified-multi-platform-push-notifications-with-ibm-mobilefirst/) supports

- [APNS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) / Push notifications in native iOS applications
- [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) / Push notifications in native Android applications
- [MPNS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx) / Push notifications in native Windows Phone applications
- Push notifications in hybrid applications